# Applications of time derivative of unit vector

Tags: vectors, differentiation

A math methods textbook I'm currently reading went into great detail deriving the following expression for the time derivative of a generic unit vector $\hat{r}$.

$$
\frac{d\hat{r}}{dt} = \frac{1}{r^2}[r\vec{v}-(\hat{r}\cdot\vec{v})\vec{r}]
$$

I understand that this formula is useful because it is based solely on the physical position vector $\vec{r}$ instead of a particular coordinate system, but I am struggling to come up with an actual example where this formula might come in handy besides looking pretty. Apologies if this question is too vague but I would appreciate any responses.